# How to change Sum Price by changing the quantity of product in user basket using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I want to change the sum price when I change the quantity.
This is view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.Product.Name</td>
                            <td><input type="number" value="@item.Count" id="Count" /></td>
                            <td id="Price">@item.Product.Price</td>
                            <td id="SumPrice">@item.SumPrice</td>
                       </tr>
                    }
```

This is the java script that I used but it doesn't work. When I change the quantity the sum price doesn't change.

```
 $('#Count').on('keyup',function(){
    var tot = $('#Price').val() * this.value;
    $('#SumPrice').val(tot);
});
```

Comment: You can't use fixed IDs (like id=Price, id=SumPrice) when you have a foreach producing multiple duplicate elements.

Comment: I didn't know. what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use same `ids` for mutliple elements instead use class. Then , using `$(this).closest("tr")` get closest `tr` reference and use `.find` to get the value of `td` which you needed to calculate.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.Count').on('keyup change', function() {
  //get closest tr -> find price class get value
  var tot = $(this).closest("tr").find('.Price').text() * this.value;
  $(this).closest("tr").find('.SumPrice').text(tot); //set value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Abc</td>
    <!--added class-->
    <td><input type="number" value="1" class="Count" /></td>
    <td class="Price">21</td>
    <td class="SumPrice">21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Xyz</td>
    <td><input type="number" value="1" class="Count" /></td>
    <td class="Price">12</td>
    <td class="SumPrice">12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you :) It worked. But can you please tell me why I can't use the same Ids?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) .Also , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page) post will help to understand more :)